# Cannot find the logical error in the stated program regarding classes and objects

Tags: java

I need to design Employee class in such a way so that the following code prints 12000; There are no run-time erros, it's a logical error that I made and cannot identify.

This is the java code

```
class Employeetester{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee a=new Employee();
    a.name="Mohammad Java Chowdhury";
    a.salary=10000;
    a.increaseSalary(20.0); //percentage
    System.out.println(a.salary);
}
}
```

This is the class file where I declared the method.

```
public class Employee{
String name;
double salary;
double exchange;
public double increaseSalary(double salary){
    salary=salary+(salary*(20.0/100.0));        
    return salary;      
}
}
```

The Output is showing 10000.

I am very new to this topic, sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: Re-read your `increaseSalary()` method, the method argument is incorrectly named and you're not even using it in the calculation.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sorry, I am new and I just learned this topic from youtube a few minutes ago, I have some lackings still. Can you please clarify the point "incorrect naming of method argument"? Thank You

Comment: In the increaseSalary() method, the calculations use the local variable declared as a parameter (salary), and does not alter the instance variable of the same name.

Comment: Oh! got it, Thanks @FredK

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper name for the parameters of your method. Also, a simpler algorithm:

```
double increaseSalary( double pct ) {
   return salary * ( 1. + (pct/100.) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood now what was the mistake

Comment: The algorithm is nice and succinct, but not equivalent with (the purpose of) the original because it doesn't change the `salary` instance variable.

Comment: @Mick Yes it does.

Comment: @DavidConrad, how; where is the new value assigned?

Comment: @Mick My apologies, I thought you misread it. *I* misread it. My mistake. I just noticed the parameter name was no longer `salary` and didn't even see it was using `return` instead of doing an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to increase salary by `20%` would be to divide current salary by `100`, which will give you `1%` and multiply that by the percentage you want to increase salary by. So something like this:

```
salary = salary + (salary / 100.0) * percentage.
```

Where `percentage` is 20 in your case.

Also, you have to distinguish `salary` as a method parameter and a class field. Either use `this` keyword to refer to a class field, or change the name of the method parameter:

```
public double increaseSalary(double salaryArg){
    salary=salaryArg+(salaryArg*(20.0/100.0));        
    return salary;      
}
```

Comment: The original algorithm is also correct but there is a bug in variable naming and usage.